# How to monitor access to shared system resources in Android?

Tags: android

In Android, there exists shared resources like some system settings, which can be read or modified by any process without permission declared.
Is there any method to monitor the access to those shared resources? Or, can we do something to make the system record the time and pid of the process which is accessing the resource?

Resources like SharedPreferences, StreamVolume, Ringer_Mode, and even some files in /proc, are almost world-readable or writable. I see that some of these are observable by using system application layer APIs such as OnSharedPreferencesChanged listener, ContentObserver, or FileObserver. then, is there any place in the system in which we can get a comprehensive observation of access to those shared resources? Maybe in a lower layer of the system(kernel)?

Comment: What kind of shared resources are you talking about ?

Comment: Agreed. Please be very specific about what you are seeking. Feel free to use actual Java code to show how you are reading and writing these "shared resources", if relevant.

Comment: You are probably talking about `SharedPreferences` class which is private to your app only. You can register OnSharedPreferencesChanged listener for any change (but not read access) to these preferences. It is not possible to expose settings through any Google API, but you can register Broadcast Event Receivers and respond to any broadcasts that other apps do to communicate with your app. Of course this approach requires that the other app knows about these broadcasts. Locale / Tasker operate in this way for example.